# Subquery Where clause invalid in select list

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, group-by, subquery

I am trying to create a numerator(num) and denominator(den) column that I will later use to create a metric value. In my numerator column, I need to have a criteria that my denominator column does not have. When I add the where clause to my sub query, I am getting the error below. I do not want to add INRInRange to my Group By clause.

> Column 'dbo.PersonDetailB.INRInRange' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

```
SELECT 
        dbo.PersonDetailSpecialty.PracticeAbbrevName, 
        (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT dbo.Problem.PID) WHERE PersonDetailB.INRInRange='True') AS num, 
        COUNT(DISTINCT dbo.Problem.PID) AS den 
FROM         
        dbo.PersonDetailB
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.PersonDetailSpecialty ON dbo.PersonDetailB.PID = dbo.PersonDetailSpecialty.PID
LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.Problem ON dbo.PersonDetailSpecialty.PID = dbo.Problem.PID

GROUP BY 
        practiceabbrevname
```

Comment: Replace with `dbo.PersonDetailSpecialty.PracticeAbbrevName` with `practiceabbrevname`,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a sub-query that counts `PersonDetailB.INRInRange` and LEFT OUTER JOIN it with the original query.

```
SELECT Main.PracticeAbbrevName, InRange.Num AS num, Main.den
FROM
    (SELECT 
            dbo.PersonDetailSpecialty.PracticeAbbrevName, 
            COUNT(DISTINCT dbo.Problem.PID) AS den 
    FROM         
            dbo.PersonDetailB
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN
            dbo.PersonDetailSpecialty ON dbo.PersonDetailB.PID = dbo.PersonDetailSpecialty.PID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
            dbo.Problem ON dbo.PersonDetailSpecialty.PID = dbo.Problem.PID
    GROUP BY 
            practiceabbrevname) Main
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
            (SELECT practiceabbrevname, COUNT(DISTINCT dbo.Problem.PID) Num WHERE PersonDetailB.INRInRange='True' GROUP BY practiceabbrevname) InRange ON Main.practiceabbrevname = InRange.practiceabbrevname
```

Comment: Along those lines, couldn't I just join a table on PID=PID and  INRInRange='True'

Comment: Yes, you could do that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this statement:

```
SELECT dbo.PersonDetailSpecialty.PracticeAbbrevName, 
       (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT dbo.Problem.PID) WHERE PersonDetailB.INRInRange = 'True') AS num, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT dbo.Problem.PID) AS den
```

is that `PersonDetailB.INRInRange1` doesn't have a unique value in each group.  It is possible that it does.  One method is to add it to the `GROUP BY`:

```
GROUP BY practiceabbrevname, PersonDetailB.INRInRange
```

Another method would use an aggregation function in the subquery:

```
SELECT dbo.PersonDetailSpecialty.PracticeAbbrevName, 
       (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT dbo.Problem.PID) WHERE MAX(PersonDetailB.INRInRange) = 'True') AS num, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT dbo.Problem.PID) AS den
```

Comment: INRInRange is a bit data type, so the Max operator is invalid.

Comment: @JohnS . . . What about adding it to the `GROUP BY`?

Answer (score 0):

Join a separate table as a different name on the where criteria that was in the sub query.

```
SELECT    PersonDetailSpecialty.PracticeAbbrevName,
          COUNT(PDTRUE.PID) as num, 
          COUNT(dbo.Problem.PID) AS den

FROM      dbo.PersonDetailSpecialty LEFT OUTER JOIN
          dbo.PersonDetailB as PDTRUE ON dbo.PersonDetailSpecialty.PID = PDTRUE.PID and PDTRUE.INRInRange='True' LEFT OUTER JOIN
          dbo.PersonDetailB ON dbo.PersonDetailSpecialty.PID = PersonDetailB.PID LEFT OUTER JOIN
          dbo.Medicate ON dbo.PersonDetailSpecialty.PID = dbo.Medicate.PID LEFT OUTER JOIN
          dbo.Problem ON dbo.PersonDetailSpecialty.PID = dbo.Problem.PID

GROUP BY  PersonDetailSpecialty.PracticeAbbrevName
```

This is the relevant code needed in the FROM section

```
dbo.PersonDetailSpecialty LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.PersonDetailB as PDTRUE 
ON dbo.PersonDetailSpecialty.PID = PDTRUE.PID and PDTRUE.INRInRange='True'
```

This lets you add

```
COUNT(PDTRUE.PID) as num,
```

as a simple part of the overall select query